# Balanced data, but unbalanced result

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, boosting

I'm fairly new to data science.

I have a multi-class classification problem with 4 classes, 100K rows.
The problem is that the classes are balanced but the prediction results are not.
(All 4 classes have 25K observations)

For example, lets say that the classes are A, B, C, and D.
Currently I'm using XGBoost and the model predictions are unbalanced.
The number of predicted observations are pretty much like this.

[ A: 5600, B: 3900, C: 5250, D: 5250 ]

I get that the features are not good enough to classify between A and B
(Model prediction for class 'C' and 'D' are not bad).
But I don't understand why the results are unbalanced.
The model tends to predict class B as class A.
I've done a lot of CV and parameter optimization but the unbalanced predictions are always there.

Is there any way to improve this unbalanced results?
For example, would it make sense to oversample, or use SMOTE to increase class B samples?

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  I'm not understanding something: how is it possible that the total of the predictions will (greatly) exceed the amount of data?  Are you perhaps describing *out of sample* predictions?  If that's so, then could you show us the information you have that allows you to conclude the predictions ought to be balanced?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It was a typo.
There are 100K rows total, 25K for each class!

Comment: The comment still applies: could you tell us what kind of "predictions" these are and explain why their total does not equal the number of rows your dataset and why you expect them to have the same distribution as in the dataset?

Comment: The examples in the passage are results of cross validation. So distribution should be the same since the folds were selected randomly.

Comment: That may be a crucially important detail, Jason.  The specifics of the cross-validation procedure are needed in order to analyze what's going on.  Please include that information within your question.

Comment: I did a 5-fold stratified cross validation. I did it a lot of times, but the results are always unbalanced in a similar way. Some times it is a little more balanced than the example, but still the model tends to predict B less than other classes. Distribution should be the same since the folds created randomly(but stratified) through xgb.cv function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might try (I am not sure whether this will help though), is to just single out class A and B, and build a binary classifier (with say XGBoost). Since in this case, they are quite balanced, you can probably judge its performance, and maybe draw some insight about your features and hyper-parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually tried A, B binary classification but the results were still unbalanced. Found some difference in feature importance, but that was all. Trying different feature subsets didn't really help.

Comment: So it seems that classes A and B are hard to differentiate to start with? As you said the results are unbalanced, it implies that the model (xgboost?) will prefer one over another. This is odd... maybe try some simpler model, say logistics regression with some regularization. The metics (e.g. AUC of ROC) might not be as good as from more complicated models, but you may check how are the 'unbalance' situation to see if there is any difference?

Comment: That seems to be a great idea to start with! Thanks a lot!